# Gazetteer Dropdown Selection not Displaying Any Data

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

Recently my Leaflet-based Gazetteer project has ceased working. There seems to be a disconnect from my PHP calling the data for the dropdown list and my map.

Since no dropdowns are selectable this causes none of my other buttons or features to work in the app.

The project is currently hosted here - https://txemaclifford.com/project1/

My index.js file calling my PHP dropdown file:

```
/* MAP INITIALISATION */
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 4);

var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoidHhlbWFjbGlmZm9yZCIsImEiOiJjbG1rbTF1ZGMwM2ZyMmpyeG9weTh1azdwIn0.4Zviz1i7DCM7LPmvGHzbPQ', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
  tileSize: 512,
  zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(map);

/* CENTER OF MAP */
map.on('moveend', function(e) {
  //console.log(map.getCenter());
  $('#current-center').html(map.getCenter().lat + "," + map.getCenter().lng);
})
map.locate();
map.on('locationfound', function(ev) {
  //console.log(ev);
  var mIcon = new L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'libs/images/marker-icon.png'
    });
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET', 
      url: 'libs/php/getCountryIso.php?get=true&lat=' + ev.latitude + '&long=' + ev.longitude, 
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
        $('#selectCountry').val(data.code);
        $('#selectCountry').change();
      }
  });
  //var marker = L.marker(ev.latlng, {icon: mIcon}).addTo(map);
});
```

My PHP file with the GeoNames API info:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['get'])){
    $url = 'http://api.geonames.org/countryCode?lat='.$_REQUEST['lat'].'&lng='.$_REQUEST['long'].'&username=txemaclifford';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $output['code'] = trim($result);
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($output);
}
?>
```

I have breakpointed the JS and nothing stands out as erroring or causing an issue, I can see it is locating the lang and lat fine.